# Task could not find "LC.exe"

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, windows-server-2012

I know that there are several questions on StackOverflow that deal with this problem - here's my variant...

Build Server: Windows Server 2012, using Jenkins
Windows SDK: 8.1 (the latest)
Compilation Configuration: x64 Debug

This started happening when I added some DevExpress dlls to the project. It compiles fine on my machine, but fails under MSBuild. The SdkToolsPath is empty in the error message - we've set that to the location of lc.exe (in the bin\x64 directory) as an environment variable, but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** Following a suggestion I saw on another post, I added the /v:diag flag to MSBuild. It would seem that, despite implications to the contrary, MSBuild *is* seeing the environment variable. I'm compiling using the 64-bit version of MSBuild, so I would think that I would need the 64-bit version of lc.exe, hence my choice of path. I'm not the admin on the build server, so I'm a bit reluctant to start asking for registry modifications - is that what it takes to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my admin found the answer: this required adding keys to the registry, but not based on what is listed in the error message.The set is as follows:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A]
"InstallationFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1A\\"
"ProductVersion"="8.1.51641"
"ProductName"="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools]
"ProductVersion"="8.1.51641"
"ComponentName"="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK"
"InstallationFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1A\\bin\\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x64]
"ProductVersion"="8.1.51641"
"ComponentName"="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK"
"InstallationFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1A\\bin\\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\\x64\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86]
"ProductVersion"="8.1.51641"
"ComponentName"="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK"
"InstallationFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1A\\bin\\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\\"
```